# Best search engine for rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search

which is the best search engine for rails 3?

1. Thinking Sphinx
2. ElasticSearch
3. Squeel

Or something else? Thanks

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. this isn't an appropriate question. please read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Also see https://github.com/d11wtq/oedipus if you need a Sphinx search client with realtime index support.

Comment: Sorry for bad post and thanks for reply. Sunspot looks promising :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sunspot. You can see http://sunspot.github.com/

Thi search gem use solr as search engine.

Features:

- Searching Objects
- Search In Depth
- Phrases
- Phrase Boosts
- Scoping (Scalar Fields)
- Pagination
- Faceting

You can see readme, https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot

I wait help you.

Regards!

Comment: I switched to ElasticSearch and Tire

Answer (score 1):

**I used sunspot** Its very easy to implement and fast search engine.